# Find $m$ so that $2^x+m^x-4^x-5^x\ge0$

Tags: calculus

Let:
$$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, \ \  f(x)= 2^x +m^x -4^x -5^x \text{ with } \ m>0$$

Find $m$ so that $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried proving that its ascending for $x>0$ and descending for $x<0$ but it didn't work

Comment: Is there any reason why $m=99999999999999909999999999999999999$ wouldn't work?

Comment: This is funny: I thought *exactly* the same as Git, yet I would have chosen $\,10^{10^{10}}\;$ , just to be sure...

Comment: @DonAntonio Laughed in real life.

Comment: @GitGud, $x=-1/2$?

Comment: Yeah, you all are forgetting negative $x$, @GitGud .

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams I could swear I read $x\ge 0$ somewhere. Seems like I misread it.

Comment: Yes, after that $\,-1/2\,$ appeared there I re-read the post, too...now, that happens to me all the time, but you Git...really! :)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, not all negative $x$, just $-1 < x < 0$.

Comment: Well, you need all negative $x$, but it is true for all $x\leq -1$ trivially. @GeorgeV.Williams

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the minimum of $f(x)$ to be at $x=0$. So $\log 2 + \log m -\log 4 - \log 5 = 0$. So $m=10$.

This doesn't show that $m=10$ solves this problem, only that $m=10$ is the only possibility.